# How should I handle remote logging with systemd?

Tags: logging, docker, systemd, journal

I run multiple CoreOS instances on Google Compute Engine (GCE). CoreOS uses systemd's journal logging feature. How can I push all logs to a remote destination? As I understand, systemd journal doesn't come with remote logging abilities. My current work-around looks like this:

```
journalctl -o short -f | ncat <addr> <ip>
```

With https://logentries.com using their [Token-based input via TCP](https://logentries.com/doc/input-token/):

```
journalctl -o short -f | awk '{ print "<token>", $0; fflush(); }' | ncat data.logentries.com 10000
```

Are there better ways?

**EDIT:** https://medium.com/coreos-linux-for-massive-server-deployments/defb984185c5

Comment: ``awk '{ print "<token>", $0; fflush(); }'`` prepends ``<token>`` for each log line.

Answer (score 10):

systemd past version 216 includes remote logging capabilities, via an client / server process pair.

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.html

Comment: it's not `systemd-journal-remote` you're looking for, it's `systemd-journal-upload` and that's available since version 216 as well.

Comment: One is the receiver, the other is the transmitter.

Answer (score 7):

A downside to using `-o short` is that the format is hard to parse; `short-iso` is better. If you're using an ELK stack, exporting as JSON is even better. A systemd service like the following will ship JSON-formatted logs to a remote host quite well.

```
[Unit]
Description=Send Journalctl to Syslog

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/journalctl -o json -f | /usr/bin/ncat syslog 515'

Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On the far side, `logstash.conf` for me includes:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port  => 1515
    codec => json_lines
    type  => "systemd"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "systemd" {
    mutate { rename => [ "MESSAGE", "message" ] }
    mutate { rename => [ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT", "program" ] }
  }
}
```

This results in the whole journalctl data structure being available to Kibana/Elasticsearch.

Comment: i think those port number should be the same right?  1515 and 515?

Answer (score 1):

> CoreOS uses systemd's journal logging feature. How can I push all logs to a remote destination?

This functionality is provided by [systemd-journal-remote](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-journal-remote.service.html). It can stream journal logs to a central logging server using [systemd-journal-upload](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journal-upload.service.8.html). If the server or network in between is down, it will stream the logs as soon as the connection is available again.

It is actually quite easy to setup:

1. Install "systemd-journal-remote" on both client and server
2. On the client configure `/etc/systemd/journal-upload.conf`:

```
[Upload]
URL=http://your_central_logserver_ip:19532
```

And configure `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-upload.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journal Remote Upload Service
Documentation=man:systemd-journal-upload(8)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
Restart=on-failure
DynamicUser=yes
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-upload --save-state
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectProc=invisible
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectHostname=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
StateDirectory=systemd/journal-upload
SupplementaryGroups=systemd-journal
SystemCallArchitectures=native
User=systemd-journal-upload
WatchdogSec=3min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

On the central logging create a directory for the clients logs:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/journal/remote/
chown systemd-journal-remote:systemd-journal-remote /var/log/journal/remote/
chmod 0750 /var/log/journal/remote/
```

And setup the config file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-remote.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Journal Remote Sink Service
Documentation=man:systemd-journal-remote(8) man:journal-remote.conf(5)
Requires=systemd-journal-remote.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --listen-http=-3 --output=/var/log/journal/remote/all.journal
LockPersonality=yes
LogsDirectory=journal/remote
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
PrivateNetwork=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectProc=invisible
ProtectClock=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectHostname=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectSystem=strict
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
User=systemd-journal-remote
WatchdogSec=3min

# If there are many split up journal files we need a lot of fds to access them
# all in parallel.
LimitNOFILE=524288

[Install]
Also=systemd-journal-remote.socket
EOF
```

Restart the systemd services and try if it works with `systemd-cat` on a client:

```
systemd-cat ls /
```

Running `journalctl --file /var/log/journal/remote/all.journal -f` should show you the output of the command on the central logging server.

I use this for our servers and it works quite nicely. I followed [this blogpost on how to setup a central logging server using systemd-journal-remote](https://www.blunix.com/blog/centralized-logging-server-on-linux-with-systemd-journal-remote.html) for a bit more detailed and comprehensive instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Kelsey Hightower's journal-2-logentries has worked pretty well for us: https://logentries.com/doc/coreos/

If you want to drop in and enable the units without Fleet:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Requires the Logentries Token as Parameter

if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo "You need to provide the Logentries Token!"; exit
0; fi

cat << "EOU1" > /etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
[Unit]
Description=Journal Gateway Service Socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/journald.sock
Service=systemd-journal-gatewayd.service
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
EOU1

cat << EOU2 > /etc/systemd/system/journal-2-logentries.service
[Unit]
Description=Forward Systemd Journal to logentries.com
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill journal-2-logentries
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm journal-2-logentries
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull
quay.io/kelseyhightower/journal-2-logentries
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c \
"/usr/bin/docker run --name journal-2-logentries \
-v /run/journald.sock:/run/journald.sock \
-e LOGENTRIES_TOKEN=$1 \
quay.io/kelseyhightower/journal-2-logentries"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOU2

systemctl enable systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
systemctl start systemd-journal-gatewayd.socket
systemctl start journal-2-logentries.service

rm -f $0
```

Answer (score 0):

A recent python package my be useful: [journalpump](https://github.com/aiven/journalpump)

With support for Elastic Search, Kafka and logplex outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rsyslog-kafka` module inside `Rsyslog`.

```
Rsyslog with moduels:
 - imfile - input file
 - omkafka - output to Kafka
```

Define json template and push them to Apache Kafka.
When logs are in Kafka...